# consulta mysql pivot

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito mostrar todo en una sola fila pero no lo logro

Esta es la consulta que estoy realizando.

```
select unidad.unidad, alumno.genero, case WHEN alumno.genero="M" then COUNT(*) END as M, case WHEN alumno.genero="F" then COUNT(*) END as F  
FROM alumno 
INNER JOIN prgalumnos on alumno.identidad = prgalumnos.identidad  
INNER JOIN programa on programa.idprograma= prgalumnos.idprograma 
INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.idunidad =programa.idunidad   
GROUP BY alumno.genero
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según se ve, debes agrupar por `unidad`, no por `genero`. O sea, en vez de `GROUP BY alumno.genero`  debería ser `GROUP BY unidad.unidad`

Comment: A primera vista tu consulta se ve bien y debería devolver lo que quieres, qué error te da o qué valores retorna. Presiento que te da el error de ONLY FULL GROUP BY, si es así agrega en tu GROUP BY a unidad.unidad, es decir `GROUP BY unidad.unidad, alumno.genero`

Comment: @Vlady pero los valores en la columna genero no son iguales, entonces como propones que agrupe también directo por eso columna¿?

Comment: @Aprendiz los valores que tiene la columna género son M o F y lo que el OP requiere es precísamente agrupar por M y F, que es lo que su consulta en teoría ya está haciendo

Comment: Pues entonces recomiendo edite por que el enunciado dice mostrar todo en un renglón

Comment: @Aprendiz lo leí incompleto, no me hagan caso xP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con una aclaración por parte de @Aprendiz y tomando en cuenta su idea de usar `GROUP_CONCAT` sugiero que tu query lo vuelvas una subconsulta de otro que unirá los resultados obtenidos por el mismo:

```
SELECT
  unidad,
  GROUP_CONCAT(M) AS M,
  GROUP_CONCAT(F) AS F
FROM
  (
    select unidad.unidad, alumno.genero, case WHEN alumno.genero="M" then COUNT(*) END as M, 
    case WHEN alumno.genero="F" then COUNT(*) END as F  
    FROM alumno 
    INNER JOIN prgalumnos on alumno.identidad = prgalumnos.identidad  
    INNER JOIN programa on programa.idprograma= prgalumnos.idprograma 
    INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.idunidad =programa.idunidad   
    GROUP BY alumno.genero
  ) AS dump_genero
GROUP BY unidad;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.... me han salvado gracias.

Answer (score 1):

- Según veo si agrupas por `unidad` eso haría que ambos renglones se fusionen en uno solo
- Sin embargo los valores que obtienes de la columna género son distintos por lo cual no pueden quedar como uno solo
- Deberías agrupar estos últimos con `GROUP_CONCAT`para que ambos valores queden dentro de la misma celda
- Finalmente agrupas por la columna no calculada que sería: `unidad.unidad`

**Propuesta**

```
select  unidad.unidad, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(alumno.genero SEPARATOR '/') AS Listado, 
        case WHEN alumno.genero="M" then COUNT(*) END as M, 
        case WHEN alumno.genero="F" then COUNT(*) END as F  
FROM alumno 
INNER JOIN prgalumnos on alumno.identidad = prgalumnos.identidad  
INNER JOIN programa on programa.idprograma= prgalumnos.idprograma 
INNER JOIN unidad on unidad.idunidad =programa.idunidad   
GROUP BY alumno.unidad;
```

La salida debería ser algo asi:

```
|         Unidad         | Género     |  M |  F |
|------------------------|------------|----|----|
|Base Hernán Acosta Mejía|    F/M     |  2 |  1 |
```

Comment: Ojo que si sólo agrupa por unidad, devolverá el total de la unidad (la suma de todos sin distinguir el género como quiere), además de que la suma estará en una sola columna, la que coincida con el género de la primera tupla de un select normal.

Comment: @Vlady por eso estoy agrupando la columna genero con group concat para que ambos valores se queden y no se pierdan al momento de agrupar

Comment: vale, acabo de ver el `GROUP_CONCAT` no me di cuenta de eso hace rato, pero de hecho eso lo hace peor, GROUP_CONCAT sólo le devolvería un string con M y F concatenados

Comment: Por eso, la ideal del OP es devolver solo un renglón, entonces la columna que al momento lo impide por tener valores distintos es género, por eso propongo que las fusione así y lo demás seguiría igual, también se cambia el group by, no veo por que tener algo asi sea peor considerando que los valores así como estan al inicio no se pueden agrupar por ser distintos

Comment: Vale, soy un gil, hoy estoy leyendo todo a medias, mejor me voy a dormir xD, voy a pensar cómo hacer lo que quiere pero se ve complicado si no usa dos queries.

Comment: Ya sé, usar la consulta del OP como subconsulta y en la consulta principal usar `GROUP_CONCAT` para los géneros y `GROUP BY` en la unidad.

Comment: Si lo consideras entonces publicalo como respuesta @Vlady